# AMQP: Process different queues in declaration order

Tags: amqp

I have a (RabbitMQ) exchange with different queues, each queue containing messages in which the order is important.

I want to select and process the earliest declared queue and progress in the order of creation. Like the exchange functioning as another queue.

How do I achieve this in AMQP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a new queue for storing the unique identifiers of other queues. Since it's FIFO, the items are placed to the queue in order. For cases when we push the currently processed queue, we simply push the same identifier again - so if not all messages got processed, their processing get queued for later.